# How to find marker on map based on title, description or latitude or longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map on which I have various markers.  The markers have title and snippets.
I want to show the info window by finding the marker on the map.  The scenario is as follows:
1.  I have a grid in which I have the Title and snippet.  When the user clicks on a row, the title and snippets are passed to the fragment containing the map.
2.  On the Create method, then I want to show the info window on the marker that have the title and snippet.

My question is how can I find a marker through it`s title and snippet and show it`s Info window?

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

private MapView map;
private static final LatLng MyRegion = new LatLng(-20, 20);

public MapFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

   //String placeName  = bundle.toString(key, defaultValue);
  //String title  = bundle.toString(key, defaultValue);

   VerifyIfMarkerExistsAndShowDetails(title, description)
}

private void VerifyIfMarkerExistsAndShowDetails(String title, String Description)
{
    GoogleMap gMap = map.getMap();
```

//How to find marker on the map having the title and description and showInfo()

```
}

private void CreateMarkers(){

    GoogleMap gMap = map.getMap();

    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Title1")
            .snippet("Description1")
            .position(new LatLng( -20.3, 19.1)));

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Title2")
            .snippet("Description2")
            .position(new LatLng(-20.1, 19.2)));    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        //Initialze mapview
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        map = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        map.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CreateMarkers();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install google play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    map.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    map.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    map.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    map.onLowMemory();
}
```

}

The xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Use a HashMap and store the markers by using the title and or the description as a key to search for the marker.

Comment: @faljour I have not understood, can you give me an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import java.util.HashMap at top then instantiate a Hashmap object,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

HashMap markerMap = new HashMap();
```

Every time you create a new marker, add it to your hashmap,

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));

markerMap.put("San Francisco", marker);
```

now in your search function, try to find the map with the search title,

```
private void VerifyIfMarkerExistsAndShowDetails(String title, String Description)
{
  Marker marker = (Marker)markerMap.get(title);
  if(marker==null)
  {
    //* show error marker does not exist
  } 
  //* else do something, maybe center the map there
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am having the error message of : Incompatible types, Required import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; Found java.lang.object at Marker marker = markerMap.get(title);

Comment: I just update the .get(title) method, it needed a (Marker) cast since the method returns an Object, also I added the import at the top for the Marker class

Comment: I have changed the code as  Marker findMarker = (Marker)markerMap.get(title); and now it works.  Thanks